# Datepicker beforeShowDay with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this function:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    var yesDate = false;
                    dataString = 'selected_date='+ date;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('/event_calendar/event_widget') ?>",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data != '<li>Sorry there are not any events for the selected date.</li>'){
                                yesDate = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return [yesDate,""];
                }
});
```

I'm trying to get the calendar to only show dates in the database and disable the rest It seems "yesDate" never gets set to true and instead always gets set to the default false.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

$.ajax is asynchronous which means yesDate will always return false because the success function of $.ajax will be called after the response comes back from the server.

You could make your ajax call synchronous but this is a bad idea.

Really what you should do is on page load find out which days are allowed and which are not, and then store that in an array or object o some kind. Then you can use that array/object to figure out which days are allowed and which are not.

Comment: What if those allowed days must change after the page loads without the possibility to reload?